# Unable to create a new instance of type 'some class'. Types cannot be instantiated without a public, no arguments constructor

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I have a class with constructor and overloaded methods in it. When i try to import that class using blazeds i get an error saying

> [RPC Fault faultString="Unable to create a new instance of type 'some class'."
>   faultCode="Server.ResourceUnavailable"
>   faultDetail="Types cannot be instantiated without a public, no arguments constructor."]

How to import class having overloaded methods using blazeds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must provide a "no args"-constructor. See [Converting data from ActionScript to Java](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/serialize_data_2.html#298895).

```
public class SomeClass
{
    // no-args constructor is required for BlazeDS
    public SomeClass() {}

    public SomeClass(int arg) {}
}

public class SomeService
{
    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        // implement to create or get a connection
    }

    public void saveSomeClass(SomeClass sc) throws SQLException
    {
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO some_table (...) VALUES (...)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: am using the constructor to connect to the database.

Comment: @Sushma: The database connection should be managed by the remoting service class and not within its data transfer objects.

Comment: Hi splash, Thanks for the solution. i could solve that problem.